# how to show up an hyperlink into html from json

Tags: javascript, html, json, geojson

I have this json:

```
tipo={
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "crs":{
        "type":"name",
        "properties":{
            "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features":[
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "pic":"./p2.png",
                "nombre":"T2V",
                "web":"www.t2v.com"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[
                    -4.45497,
                    36.692029
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "pic":"./p2.png",
                "nombre":"NETBLUE",
                "web":"www.netblue.es"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[
                    -4.427596,
                    36.713663
                ]
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

I need to show up the hyperlink of each fields in a popup in html with this code: 
`

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

info.update = function (props) {
    // console.log(props);
    this._div.innerHTML = ''
    +(props? '<br><img src="'+props.pic+'"style="height:75px; display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">': '')
    +(props? '<b><center style="color:#838383; margin-top:10px;">'+props.nombre+'</center></b>': '')
    +(props? '<br><b><center style="color:#838383"><a href>'+props.web+'</a></center></b>': '');

    this._div.innerHTML += '<br /><img src="link.png" style="background:#FFC627; margin-left:20px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:0px">';
};
info.addTo(map);`
```

But the problem is that the hyperlink shows up in the popup with the tipical underlines  but when i click in the hyperlink, the webpage only refresh, it doesn't go to the respective webpage of the json.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Its because your link is not valid, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'<a href>'+props.web+'</a>'` isn't how the links are supposed to work (in fact, it's invalid HTML)

The `href` attribute should contain as value the address of the link.

`'<a href="' + props.web + '">I am a working link</a>'`

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) for more informations about the `<a></a>` tag.

My last sentence could be written in HTML such way

```
<p>
    Please take a look at the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a">documentation</a> for more informations about the <code><a></a></code> tag.
</p>
```

Comment: Also highly possible they want `<a href="' + props.web + '">' + props.web + '</a>`

Comment: @freefaller indeed, but this example is used to show the effect of the text between `<a></a>`

Comment: Fair comment, make sense

Comment: Now it works!. The Cid and freefaller answer are correctly. Also, i wrote the url in the json incorrectly. I forgot write https://